# please explain the difference between two way hand shake and three way for PAP and CHAP

Tags: networking, ppp

well the difference i general

specifically for

-two way - PAP

-three way - CHAP

and

what has it got to do with how the connection terminates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [PPP Authentication Using the ppp chap hostname and ppp authentication chap](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/tech/tk713/tk507/technologies_configuration_example09186a0080094333.shtml)

> PAP authentication involves a two-way
>   handshake where the username and
>   password are sent across the link in
>   clear text; hence, PAP authentication
>   does not provide any protection
>   against playback and line sniffing.
>
> CHAP authentication, on the other
>   hand, periodically verifies the
>   identity of the remote node using a
>   three-way handshake. After the PPP
>   link is established, the host sends a
>   "challenge" message to the remote
>   node. The remote node responds with a
>   value calculated using a one-way hash
>   function. The host checks the response
>   against its own calculation of the
>   expected hash value. If the values
>   match, the authentication is
>   acknowledged; otherwise, the
>   connection is terminated.